# Setting subdomains to multiple computers for Remote Desktop/VNC

Tags: domain, port, subdomain, rdp, vnc

I have some computers set up at home and would like to be able to access them from anywhere.
I have achieved this by forwarding ports accordingly:

```
public | computer | private | Details
5001 | computer 1 | 3389 | Computer 1 RDP
5002 | computer 1 | 5900 | Computer 1 VNC
5003 | computer 2 | 3389 | Computer 2 RDP
```

If i try to connect using the publicIp followed by the appropriate public port everything works fine.

I am trying however to add them as a subdomain to my personal domain, so I would be able to connect using a subdomain rather than memorising the ip or port. (eg: connect to svn.domain.com, Not domain.com:5001)

what kind of record should I add, as none I tried work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SVR` records, if those are supported by the client.

Another solution is to get IPv6 on your network. You can get that through a tunnel provider, if your ISP is one of those still having the delusion that they don't need to upgrade their network to support IPv6.

I am aware that the client might not always be on a network with IPv6 support. There is a solution for that.

If you install a Teredo client on the client machine, it can get an IPv6 address on any network where it can send and receive UDP packets. Teredo is usually very unreliable, but the reason it is unreliable is because the networks you connect to might not have their own Teredo relay.

A Teredo client connecting to your network at home can be very reliable, if you just install a Teredo relay on your router.

On Linux platforms the Miredo package can be installed to get a Teredo client or Teredo relay (it operates as client by default, but can be configured to operate as relay).

On Windows Teredo support is built in newer versions. You may need to enable it.

Comment: do you know what the _Service . _PROTOCOL  need to be please?

Comment: @user221119 http://serverfault.com/questions/504380/srv-dns-record-with-custom-ports-am-i-misunderstanding-what-srv-is-supposed-to#504415

Answer (score 2):

None, this is not possible with DNS records.

Comment: Is there an alternative to having to remember the ip and port however? Without the client having to use anything extra, like VPN.

Comment: Not that I know of for this specific protocols. The answer to this problem is IPv6 in the end, but who knows when this will be finally available everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

For remote desktop to multiple windows machines, you want a Remote Desktop Gateway server.  This will allow you to connect to any system the RDG server can reach and only requires the RDG server be accessible over HTTPS.